# How to validate selection option using jquery and toolpister

Tags: javascript, jquery, symfony

I want to validate my dropdown menu list, and check if the user has selected the not null option or not.
This is my code:

```
$('#rappelform input[type="text"]').tooltipster({
  trigger: 'custom', // default is 'hover' which is no good here
  onlyOne: false, // allow multiple tips to be open at a time
  position: 'right' // display the tips to the right of the element
});
$('#rappelform input[type="select"]').tooltipster({
  trigger: 'custom', // default is 'hover' which is no good here
  onlyOne: false, // allow multiple tips to be open at a time
  position: 'right' // display the tips to the right of the element
});
```

And my HTML markup:

```
<select id="message" name="message[centre]" class="textbox">
  <option value="">choose value </option>      
  <option value="abc">select 1 </option>  
  <option value="abc">select 2 </option>   
</select>
```

For the input text, I don't have any problem, but with the select option, I want to show a message if the user does not select any option.

Answer (score 0):

Why you dont use `required` attribute ?

```html
<form>
<select id="message" name="message[centre]" class="textbox" required>
  <option value="">choose value </option>      
  <option value="abc">select 1 </option>  
  <option value="abc">select 2 </option>   
</select>
 <input type="submit"  value="Submit"/>
</form>
```

Comment: I want to validate it using jquery, I ask if this code is correct $('#rappelform input[type="select"]').tooltipste